# How to get AWS policy needed to run a specific CLI command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS. I am trying to import an OVA to a AMI and use it for an EC2 instance as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html):

One of the commands it asks you to run is

`aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids import-ami-1234567890abcdef0`

When I do this I get
`An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeImportImageTasks operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

I believe this means I need to add the appropriate Role (with a policy to be able to describe-import-image-tasks) to my cli user.

In the IAM console, I see this search feature to filter policies for a role which I will assign to my user. However it doesn't seem to have any results for `describe-import-image-tasks`

[image]

Is there an easy way to determine which policies are needed to run an AWS Cli command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an easy way. The CLI commands usually (but not always) map to a single IAM action that you need permission to perform. In your case, it appears you need the `ec2:DescribeImportImageTasks` permission, as [listed here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html).

Comment: I guess some function for describe-import-image-tasks -> ec2:DescribeImportImageTasks or (CLI Command->Actions) would be helpful. How did you know which webpage to look on? Is there a service authorization reference webpage for every AWS resource type?

Comment: On that page I linked you to, there is a list of AWS services down the left side of the page. You are running `aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks`. The first parameter to the `aws` command is the service name. In your case the service name is `ec2`. So I looked at the EC2 service page on that IAM documentation site. Then I searched for `"DescribeImportImageTasks"` on that page because your error message said "the DescribeImportImageTasks operation"